# How to use value from dynamic field Sequelize?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm counting associated rows and write this number to **modelTwoCount** field, how can I use this field to filter **ModelOne.totalCount** rows, something like **totalCount: Sequelize.col('modelTwoCount')**, but it doesn't work, because **modelTwoCount** not a column

```
ModelOne.findAll({
        where: {
            totalCount: /* need to use number from generated modelTwoCount field */,
        },
        subQuery: false,
        include: {
            model: ModelTwo,
            where: {
                completed: false,
            },
        },
        group: ['ModelTwo.modelOneId'],
        attributes: {
            include: [[sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("ModelTwo.modelOneId")), "modelTwoCount"]],
        },
    });
```